# Is it possible to force a concept as valid to avoid a std::variant recursion concept check error?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I can't compile on clang++16 a previous working code because of concept check recursion. The compiler gives me the following error:

> error: satisfaction of constraint 'requires { { __t < __u } -> __boolean_testable; { __u < __t } -> __boolean_testable; }' depends on itself

This is the minimal code that replicates the error, working in previous versions:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

struct var;
typedef std::vector<var> var_vector;
typedef std::variant<int, var_vector> var_base_type;

struct var : public var_base_type {
  using var_base_type::var_base_type;
  bool operator<(const var &to) const {
    if (index() != to.index())
      return index() < to.index();
    if (holds_alternative<int>(*this))
      return get<int>(*this) < get<int>(to);
    if (holds_alternative<var_vector>(*this))
      return get<var_vector>(*this) < get<var_vector>(to);
    return false;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << (var(10) < var(20)) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a way in the concept syntax to force the concept as valid in the `var_vector` type?

Comment: It does compile with `-stdlib=libc++`: https://godbolt.org/z/as3zG67xM

Comment: I'm guessing somewhere there's a requirement for type completeness, and that's tripping up the library.

Comment: Isn't the code in `var::operator<` redundant? `std::variant` already implements its own [`operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/operator_cmp) to compare the values of 2 `variant`s similarly to how this code is doing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau without the operator< doesn't compile unless I use -stdlib=libc++, and that solution brings to me a lot of more problem with linking other libraries. So I suppose that in the future the operator will be redundant to me, but not now.